# show title if one of post meta exist

Tags: metabox

I have 4 metabox `facebook`, `twitter`, `instagram`, `youtube` with title "Follow Us". I am using [this](http://pastebin.com/7UuPiXFH) code to show facebook logo and link.

So if there are a value in facebook metabox I got the logo and the link.

Now my question, if One of this 4 metabox (facebook, twitter, instagram, youtube) has a value ( at least one of this 4 ), I need to show title "Follow Us on".

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer below way,

```
$fb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_facebookpage', true);
$twitter = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_facebookpage', true);
//etc...

if($fb != "" || $twitter != "" || $instagram = ""){
    echo "Follow Us On";
    if($fb != ""){ ?>    
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $fb; ?>">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images2/service-fb.png" width="25px" height="33px" alt="" align="right">
      </a>
    <?php }
    // And so on.....
}
```